# Including Jquery statements into a javascript popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am trying to create a popup window of a html page that includes jquery. However I think I might have some syntex issue. This is a small example of the code. Much thanks for any help

```
var zWindow;
zWindow=window.open('','newwin','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=ye s,resizable=yes,left=10,top=10,width=540,height=600');
zWindow.document.open();
zWindow.document.write("<h2>$**{noSearchResultsHeaderText}**</h2>");
zWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: @user why are taking this approach , have a place holder like a div , construct your string and finally do a .html(string) , it will attach the string to the dom

Answer (score 1):

I think there's some confusion here around jQuery templates, they're not used in direct generation, you should just concatenate the string, like this:

```
var zWindow=window.open('','newwin','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=ye s,resizable=yes,left=10,top=10,width=540,height=600');
zWindow.document.open();
zWindow.document.write("<h2>" + noSearchResultsHeaderText + "</h2>");
zWindow.document.close();
```